# How to add dummy values to a dropdownlist in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am following few tutorials for creating MVC3 application.
I saw example of adding dropdownlist bound to a model.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Vehicle.Model, new List<SelectListItem>(), String.Empty, new { style = "width: 100px;", size = "1" })
```

But i just want to add few contant values i.e. not coming from the DB, but just want to add few items to dropdownlist in code, how can i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@{
     var modellist = new List<VehicleModels>()
     {
         new VehicleModels() { ID= 1, Name="A"},
         new VehicleModels() { ID= 2, Name="B"},
         new VehicleModels() { ID= 3, Name="C"},
         new VehicleModels() { ID= 4, Name="D"}
     }
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Vehicle.Model, new SelectList(modellist, "ID" , "Name"), String.Empty, new { style = "width: 100px;", size = "1" })
```

Comment: So this means i can bind anything which is IOEnumerable, correct? For ex List

Comment: But how do i bind it to a list of string ex: @{
     var modellist = new List<String>()
     {
         "Device1",
         "Device2",
         "Device3",
         "Device4"
     }
}